# Corresponding long exact sequence to boundaries-cycle exact sequence to $0 \to Z \to C \to B(-1) \to 0$ breaks up into short exact sequences.

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The following is Exercise 1.3.4. from Weibel's *Homological Algebra*.

> Let $C$ be a chain complex. Then, we have the associated exact sequence $$0 \to Z \to C \to B(-1) \to 0,$$ where $Z$ is the complex of cycles (kernels) and $B$ of boundaries (images).
> Show that the corresponding long exact sequence of homology breaks up into short exact
> sequences.

This is right after the discussion on the long exact sequence of homologies associated to a short exact sequence. From what I understand, we have a long exact sequence of the homologies given as

$$\cdots \to H_{n}(Z) \to H_{n}(C) \to H_{n - 1}(B) \xrightarrow{\partial} H_{n - 1}(Z) \to \cdots. \tag{1}$$

So let us compute the homologies of $Z$ and $B(-1)$. From what I see, the maps $Z_{n} \to Z_{n - 1}$ and $B_{n - 1} \to B_{n - 2}$ are simply the restriction of differentials and are simply $0$. (The former is zero since $Z$ is the kernel. The latter is zero since $B$ is contained in the kernel.)

As a result, the homologies are simply the modules themselves. Thus, $(1)$ simplifies to

$$\cdots \to Z_{n} \to H_{n}(C) \to B_{n - 1} \xrightarrow{\partial} Z_{n - 1} \to H_{n - 1}(C) \to \cdots.$$

How does the above break into short exact sequences? I have a feeling that the maps $Z_n \to H_n(C)$ are simply the quotient maps, the maps $H_{n}(C) \to B_{n - 1}$ are $0$ maps, and the connecting homomorphism $\partial$ becomes the inclusion map. Is that correct?
How does one interpret that as "breaking up into short exact sequences"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Break up into short exact sequences" usually means splitting the groups in the chain complex so that the long exact sequence is a direct sum of short exact sequences.  As you suspected, the connecting homomorphisms are inclusions, since for $b\in B_{n-1}$, there is a $c\in C_n$ with $b=\partial c$, and then the connecting homomorphism $\partial$ applied to $b$ is defined to be $\partial b = \partial c$, which is an element of $Z_{n-1}$.

The maps $H_n(C) \to B_{n-1}$ are indeed $0$ maps, since they are given by taking the differential, but elements of $H_n(C)$ are represented by cycles.

So, the long exact sequence is direct sums of the following short exact sequences, each copy shifted over by 3
$$0 \to B_n \to Z_{n} \to H_{n}(C) \to 0$$
That is, the long exact sequence looks like this:
$$\cdots \to H_{n+1}(C)\oplus0 \to 0\oplus B_n \to Z_{n} \to H_{n}(C) \oplus 0\to 0 \oplus B_{n-1} \to Z_{n-1} \to H_{n-1}(C)\oplus 0 \to \cdots $$

This is related to a construction where you take an exact sequence
$$A_{i-2} \xrightarrow{f} A_{i-1} \to A_{i} \to A_{i+1} \xrightarrow{g} A_{i+2}$$
and then extract a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{coker}f \to A_i \to \ker g \to 0$$
In some circumstances, $\operatorname{coker}f$ and $\ker g$ split $A_{i-1}$ and $A_{i+1}$, and you can use short exact sequences obtained in this way to break up a long exact sequence.